# docker-compose failed on friend's linux computer

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, path, dockerfile

I'm starting to learn Docker, and i'm following this (very) long tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zUHg7xjIqQ

I have a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml .

It work fine on my fine on my machine (we all know this sentence), but when my friend pulled what i've done, he obtains this error message:
`Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "volume": invalid mount path: 'node_back/node_modules' mount path must be absolute`

Here are my files:

Dockerfile in node_back/ :

```
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

docker-compose at the root:

```
services:
  back-container:
    build: ./node_back
    image: back-image:tag
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./node_back:/app
      - ./node_back/node_modules
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
```

I used the command:
`sudo docker-compose up -d`
to launch the docker script.

Can somebody explain my error, and why it work on my side?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm surprised you say that it works fine on your computer. The `./node_back/node_modules` line will always give this error, AFAIK.

Comment: yup that is strange. I triyng the Berkay Korkmaz's solution

Comment: I'd recommend deleting those `volumes:` lines, incidentally.  What they get you is a very roundabout way to run `node` on your host system that requires administrator permissions and that ignores updates to the `package.json` file.  You can use `node` for day-to-day development, and if you need to use Docker, run the code that's actually built into the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you forgot ':' on volume path line.

```
./node_back/node_modules
```

you should be used ':' for separate your local volume and docker volume

```
./node_back/node_modules:WHERE-YOUR-WANT-DOCKER-PATH
```

Comment: It works on my side, asking the friend if it's ok on his PC. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this: ```- ./node_back/node_modules:/app/node_modules```